# Adding ruby global variable to a html hyperlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I have the following code in my html.erb file in my ROR application.

```
<% $tmp_bug="something" %>
<a href="http://jira.copivia.com:8080/browse/#{$tmp_bug}">JIRA</a>
```

I want to add that ruby variable to the end of the hyperlink. This does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% $tmp_bug="something" %>
<a href="http://jira.copivia.com:8080/browse/<%= $tmp_bug %>">JIRA</a>
```